# Using Custom Font for Android Studio Editor

Tags: android-studio, fonts

I installed my favorite programming editor font - Inconsolata - on my Macbook Pro, but I can't seem to get it working in Android Studio.  I've confirmed that the font works correctly on eclipse, so it is definitely installed correctly.

In the Android Studio options, it just shows a bunch of strange boxed A characters.  If I select the font, my entire editor becomes boxed A characters.

Anyone know how to make this font work in Android Studio?

[image: What Inconsolata looks like in Android Studio options.]

Comment: It is because of the format of the font, its a OTF. (Open Type Font).

Answer (score 7):

I got Inconsolata working by unselecting "Show only monospaced fonts." Before that, Inconsolata wasn't even showing up. I'm using Windows, but it might work for you.

[image]

Comment: Inconsolata is not a default font on OSX

Comment: Yes, it is not default on windows either. I had to install it first

Answer (score 6):

The most simplest way to **change font** in Android studio editor is given below:

Step 1: Go to directory C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\fonts

Step 2: Paste the font with.ttf extension i.e.,(True Type Font) file of your custom font.

Step 3: Open Android Studio and set the font through **Settings/General/Font** in the File Menu. But, make sure that you have to re-open the Android Studio if already open.

Answer (score 0):

step one => font folder address changed to C:\ your android address file \jbr\lib\fonts
for other step follow Parth Shah and Mohd Asim

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).